# Сохранение всех данных из текстбоксов и загрузка обратно

Tags: c#

На форме есть текстбоксы ( 10 шт )

Мне нужно после ввода данных в эти текстбоксы сохранить их ( на кнопку ), после создать кнопку которая загрузить те же данные что вводил в каждый из текстбоксов (в точно те же где была запись )

Как такое реализовать?

Comment: Что именно вам непонятно в этой задаче? Если бы был один текстбокс - вы бы смогли сохранить этот текст в файл? Прочитать обратно? Чем-то десять кнопок в этом плане кардинально отличаются от одной? При фиксированном числе текстбоксов задача не выглядит какой-то сложной.

Comment: @AK, Ну для одного я бы использовал так: `File.WriteAllText("Settings.txt", TextBox.Text);`, Но что мне для каждого текстбокса записывать такую же конструкцию?

Comment: Вам алгоритм действия или готовый код нужен? :DDD

Comment: @Luser используя все тот же `File.WriteAllText("Settings.txt", TextBox.Text);` можно проходиться по текстбоксам и записывать информацию, например foreach-ем

Comment: @biggiemot, А как потом загружать данные в те же самые текстбоксы ?

Comment: @Luser смотря куда вы будете их записывать и как. Покажите примерную реализацию записи данных, а там будет видно как читать данные и передавать в текстбоксы

Comment: Если вопрос касается алгоритма, то можно что угодно придумать. Можно записывать в какой-то каталог файлы с именами 1, 2, 3 и так далее и из них потом восстанавливать; можно более сложные схемы придумывать -- типа Dictionary<int, string> и записывать в один файл.

Comment: @AK, Я очень мало видел примеров подобных, поэтому обратился сюда. Если поможете написать метод который сохраняет и читает данные мне было бы полезно. Просто я мало в этом шарю :( к сожалению.

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы читать:

```
StreamReader read = new StreamReader("mytext.txt");
textBox1.Text = read.ReadLine();
textBox2.Text = read.ReadLine();
textBox3.Text = read.ReadLine();
read.Close();
```

Чтобы писать:

```
StreamWriter write = new StreamWriter("mytext.txt");
write.WriteLine(textBox1.Text);
write.WriteLine(textBox2.Text);
write.WriteLine(textBox3.Text);
write.Close();
```